# Validate Conditional Attributes of Python Class

Tags: python-3.x

I have a class with a handful of attributes.  I can use the @property decorator to validate each attribute.  However, I want to also validate conditional attributes.  Right now I am using a validate function I call in the **init** method.  Is there a better way?

Here is how I am doing it now.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.validate()
   
    def validate(self):
        if self.x > 100 and self.y > 100:
           raise ValueError("Object outside of bounds!")
        elif isintance(self.y, int) and not isintance(self.x, int):
           raise ValueError("Mismatched types!")
        elif...
```

Comment: What are the conditions you'd like to validate ?

Comment: This is a dummy example but the conditions I am validating are in the validate function.  X and Y cannot both be greater than 100, though one of the two can be.  X and Y cannot be different types.

Answer (score 0):

I would validate within `__init__` either directly of with a helper function.

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        if x > 100 and y > 100:
            raise ValueError("x and y cannot both be greather than 100")
        if not (isinstance(x, type(y)) and isinstance(y, type(x))):
            raise ValueError("x and y have different types")
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class Bar:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.validate(x, y)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @staticmethod
    def validate(x, y) -> bool:
        if x > 100 and y > 100:
            raise ValueError("x and y cannot both be greather than 100")
        if not (isinstance(x, type(y)) and isinstance(y, type(x))):
            raise ValueError("x and y have different types")
        return True
```